# Are the usage of tenses correct here?

Tags: grammar, tense

Source:http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/mrsfunnybones/kohinoor-and-other-british-gems/

> If trolls badger me, I have a comeback, ‘Oops sorry! Burnt my bridges there as well.’

It should be , 'I will have a comeback.Sorry!Burn my bridges there'.

Why the writer says , 'as well'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the tenses are correct.

In saying "I *have* a comeback," The speaker is implying that he already has a response prepared, since he knows he will be badgered by the troll. He knows what he is going to say.

"*Burnt* my bridges" is also the correct tense here, but he's using an implied pronoun. He really means to say "*I* burnt my bridges." (Omitting *I* is relatively common in spoken English—although it's not strictly correct.)

"As well" in this context means "too" or "also." This implies that he has burnt multiple bridges.

Comment: It should be ,'burn my bridges'?

Comment: No, "burnt my bridges" is correct. I've edited my answer to clarify.